# Show div inside of an li element on hover with css does't work

Tags: html, css

Somehow I cant make it works, I am trying to show a `div` (inside of `li` element) on hover of that `img` or `li` element. Could anyone help me with this?

HTML

```
<ul class="step-nav clearfix" id="leftright">
  <li class="pret button" id="pret" style="left:50%; top:50%; margin-left: -635px; position:fixed">
    <a class="pLocation linkFX" style="outline: 0;" href="blah"><img src="images/arrow.png"></a>
    <a class="sublinkCat" style="color: #fff;" href="blah">
      <div class="titlePR">
        <h1 class="title" style="margin-top: 25px;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; text-align: center;">Title</h1>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.titlePR {
  display: none;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-left: -600px;
  position:fixed;
  width: 154px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #222;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.pret:hover + .titlePR {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code in a readable format

Comment: Cant made it, something wrong here is with UI, working on it

Comment: Code is on pastebin... sorry about this, but i cant put it here due to  some problem with this UI... wont work on my chromium browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
.pret:hover + .titlePR { display: block; }
```

To:

```
.pret:hover .titlePR { display: block; } /* .titlePR is a descendant,
                                            not a sibling */
```

**Note**: here `+` is not applicable because `.titlePR` is class inside the `li` element and not a sibling